# VBA Code to copy set vales from a master sheet to the last row of multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to using VBA but will try to be as clear and succinct as possible with my problem.

I have a regular set of data (85 rows) that I copy into a "master sheet" on Excel.

I want to write a code that copies each row of the master sheet onto the next empty row on a separate sheet (85 sheets).

I know how to find and set the last row on any given sheet but I cannot workout how to paste into the last row of the destination sheet without having to "set"/define the last row of each sheet separately.

To better explain:

I want to take the values from A2:A4 on the "master sheet" and paste them into the next empty row of sheet "Aa"
Then copy the values from B2:B4 on the "master sheet" and paste them into the next empty row of sheet "Bb"
Then the values from C2:C4 on the "master sheet" and paste into the next empty row of sheet "Cc"... (and so on)

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to determine the last row for each sheet separately or just use `.End(xlUp)` when pasting.

Comment: And you can paste everything at once... Do you need the initial range format to be kept? Is it a big range to be copied?

Comment: Do all the columns to be pasted have the same number of rows? Can you specify which is the last column to be pasted? Will this range be pasted in worksheets of the same workbook, or in another wb?

Comment: Try setting a Worksheet object and then you can reuse the code.

Comment: You're talking about 85 rows, then you want to copy little 3-cell column ranges to rows of the other worksheets. You need to clarify if 85 is columns or rows, if the 3-cell column ranges maybe need to be transposed into rows, will the new data in the sheets start in the first column. All this can be easily solved. The only hard work could be writing down the worksheet names and the ranges if they are not adjacent. There is an edit button below your post. Use it to edit your question with clarifications. it's a piece of cake.

Comment: Didn't my answer code solve your problem? At least a little feedback will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I asked some questions but no reply... Try, please the next code. It is designed to work on the same workbook (ThisWorkbook), but commented for using of a different one. The code uses a generic range, including last K column, but it can be extended by simple replacing of K with your last column letter. It also assumes that all columns have the same number of rows.

The code uses an array and working in memory, should be fast enough. Please test it and give us some feedback:

```
Sub pasteRangeFromMasterSheet()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, lastRow As Long, lastR As Long, rngArr As Variant
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'you have to use here your 'master sheet'
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'master sheet last row
 rngArr = sh.Range("A2:K" & lastRow).value 'you have to use your last column letter instead of 'K'
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'in case of a different workbook, you must set it here
 For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> sh.Name Then 'in case of copying in sheets of the same workbook
        lastR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last (empty) row
        'Drop the values in the last empty row:
        ws.Range("A" & lastR).Resize(UBound(rngArr, 1), UBound(rngArr, 2)).value = rngArr
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

The code can be adapted to also copy the column headers in case of an empty sheet (ws).